# Is "claimer" primarily a term for a customer notorious for their frivolous complaints?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In Japanese this English loanword is being used in this way, and I am curious as to whether the usage is technically correct.

While I realize that in English the definition of "claimer" extends beyond only picky customers or people trying to file petty claims against others, I do wonder how common this usage is.

I did find a couple of [example sentences](http://claimer.inasentence.org/use-claimer-in-a-sentence/) that seem to be using it to mean someone filing a claim that is illegitimate.

The way "claimer" (クレーマー, kure-ma-) is used in Japanese often implies that the person making the claim is demanding something unreasonable. Although I would guess it is also possible to be a claimer making a claim that *is* reasonable. Or would we not label a reasonable person filing a complaint as a "claimer" and reserve that word for only the unreasonable ones?

I'm hoping for some clarification. Is this usage "Japanese English" or is it just unfamiliar to me?

Comment: I think this is Japanese English; I wasn't familiar with it before reasing your question. In legal contexts, I think the usual noun is *claimant.* For someone who is complaining, there are other words.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a use I've ever heard, and while I would understand it as "somebody who claims", I certainly wouldn't get the intended meaning without a lot of context.